# Online one spider is running from from scrapy import cmdline

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

This is my python script to run my spider name ndtv ,republic , thehindu ,zee and indiatv

```
from scrapy import cmdline
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl ndtv".split())
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl republic".split())
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl thehindu".split())
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl zee".split())
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl indiatv".split())
```

when I run my script then only the first spider i.e. ndtv spider is running and script close without open/running the other spider. I need a way to run all spider.

Comment: Explained in Scrapy documentation: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process